# Titan Db ignoring index

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have a graph with a couple of indices. They're two composite indices with label restraints. (both are exactly the same just on different properties/labels).
One definitely seems to work but the other doesn't. I've done the following profile() to doubled check:

One is called `KeyOnNode` : property `uid` and label `node` :

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("node").has("uid", "xxxxxxxx").profile().cap(...)
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TitanGraphStep([~label.eq(node), uid.eq(dammit_...                     1           1           2.565    96.84
  optimization                                                                                 1.383
  backend-query                                                        1                       0.231
SideEffectCapStep([~metrics])                                          1           1           0.083     3.16
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           2.648        -
```

The above is perfectly acceptable and works well. I'm assuming the magic line is `backend-query`.

The other is called `NameOnSuperNode` : property `name` and label `supernode`:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("supernode").has("name", "xxxxxxxx").profile().cap(...)
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TitanGraphStep([~label.eq(supernode), name.eq(n...                     1           1        5763.163   100.00
  optimization                                                                                 2.261
  scan                                                                                         0.000
SideEffectCapStep([~metrics])                                          1           1           0.073     0.00
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        5763.236        -
```

Here the query takes an outrageous amount of time and we have a `scan` line. I originally wondered if the index wasn't commit through the management system but alas the following seems to work just fine :

```
gremlin> m = graphT.openManagement(); 
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@73c1c105
gremlin> index = m.getGraphIndex("NameOnSuperNode")
==>NameOnSuperNode
gremlin> index.getFieldKeys()
==>name
gremlin> import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeDefinitionCategory.*
==>null
gremlin> sv = m.getSchemaVertex(index)
==>NameOnSuperNode
gremlin> rel = sv.getRelated(INDEX_SCHEMA_CONSTRAINT, Direction.OUT)
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.SchemaSource$Entry@26b2b8e2
gremlin> sse = rel.iterator().next()
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.SchemaSource$Entry@2d39a135
gremlin> sse.getSchemaType()
==>supernode
```

I can't just reset the db at this point. Any help pinpointing what the issues could be would be amazing, I'm hitting a wall here.
Is this a sign that I need to reindex?

INFO: Titan DB 1.1 (TP 3.1.1)

Cheers

**UPDATE :** I've found that the index in question is not in a `REGISTERED` state:

```
gremlin> :> m = graphT.openManagement(); index = m.getGraphIndex("NameOnSuperNode"); pkey = index.getFieldKeys()[0]; index.getIndexStatus(pkey)
==>INSTALLED
```

How do I get it to register? I've tried `m.updateIndex(index, SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get(); m.commit(); graphT.tx().commit();` but it doesn't seem to do anything

**UPDATE 2 :** I've tried regitering the index in order to reindex with the following :

```
gremlin> m = graphT.openManagement(); 
index = m.getGraphIndex("NameOnSuperNode") ; 
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeDefinitionCategory.*; 
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem; 
m.updateIndex(index, SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graphT, "NameOnSuperNode").status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).timeout(20, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call();
m.commit();
graphT.tx().commit()
```

But this isn't working. I still have my index in the `INSTALLED` status and I'm still getting a timeout. I've checked that there were no open transactions.  Anyone have an idea? FYI the graph is running on a single server and has ~100K vertices and ~130k edges.

Answer (score 8):

So there are a few things that can be happening here:

1. If both of those indices you describe were not created in the same transaction (and the problem index in question was created in after the `name` `propertyKey` was already defined) then you should issue a reindex, as per [Titan docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/indexes.html):

   > The name of a graph index must be unique. Graph indexes built against
   >   newly defined property keys, i.e. property keys that are defined in
   >   the same management transaction as the index, are immediately
   >   available. Graph indexes built against property keys that are already
   >   in use require the execution of a reindex procedure to ensure that the
   >   index contains all previously added elements. Until the reindex
   >   procedure has completed, the index will not be available. It is
   >   encouraged to define graph indexes in the same transaction as the
   >   initial schema.
2. The index may be timing out the process that takes to move from `REGISTERED` to `INSTALLED`, in which case you want to use `mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus()`. You can even specify the amount of time you are willing to wait here.
3. Make sure there are no open transactions on your graph or the index status will indeed not change, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643409/titandb-index-not-changing-state).
4. This is clearly not the case for you, but there is a bug in Titan (fixed in JanusGraph via [this PR](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/192)) such that if you create an index against a newly created propertyKey as well as a previously used propertyKey, the index will get stuck in the `REGISTERED` state
5. Indexes will not move to `REGISTERED` unless every Titan/JanusGraph node in the cluster acknowledges the index creation. If your indexes are getting stuck in the `INSTALLED` state, there is a chance that the other nodes in the system are not acknowledging the indexes existence. This can be due to issues with another server in the cluster, backfill in the messaging queue Titan/JanusGraph uses to talk with each other, or most unexpectedly: the existence of phantom instances. These can occur every time your server is killed through non-normal JVM shutdown processes, i.e. `kill -9` the server due to it being stuck in thrash the world garbage collection. If you expect backfill to be the problem, the comments in [this class](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/diskstorage/log/kcvs/KCVSLog.java) offer good insight to customizable configuration options that may help fix the problem. To check for the existence of phantom nodes, use [this function](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/database/management/ManagementSystem.java#L200) and then [this function](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/database/management/ManagementSystem.java#L210) to kill the phantom instances.

Comment: Thank you! I will try some things. Do you by any chance know off the top of your head how to extend the timeout for `awaitGraphIndexStatus()`? Also what is the state I need to be in to reindex? This can't be done from `INSTALLED`

Comment: The second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656531/unable-to-create-a-composite-index-stuck-at-installed) should answer both of those questions for you! Good luck!

Comment: I meant to say first^

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've added a second update to my post as I can't seem to make any progress changing the index status. I think you are correct as  `name` is a property that is defined in other label restrained indices, but still stuck...

Comment: Note that the bug in #4 has been fixed in JanusGraph. With [this PR](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/192) you can specify multiple statuses to await

Comment: @David You pointed out "You can even specify the amount of time you are willing to wait here." in point 2 of your answer. Can you please also point out how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed config to your graph.
If you used backend is cassandra, you must config with elasticsearch.
If you used backend is hbase, you must config with caching.
Read more in link below:
 https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/configuration.html