# JanusGraph:Some key(s) on index verticesIndex do not currently have status REGISTERED

Tags: indexing, mixed, janusgraph

I have some questions when I build a JanusGraph Mixed index.
This is my code:

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement();
idx = mgmt.getGraphIndex('zhh1_index');
prop = mgmt.getPropertyKey('zhang');
mgmt.addIndexKey(idx, prop);
prop = mgmt.getPropertyKey('uri');
mgmt.addIndexKey(idx, prop);
prop = mgmt.getPropertyKey('age');
mgmt.addIndexKey(idx, prop);
mgmt.commit();
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'zhh1_index').status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
mgmt = graph.openManagement();
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex('zhh1_index'),SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();
mgmt.commit();
vertex2=graph.addVertex(label,'zhh1');
vertex2.property('zhang','male');
vertex2.property('uri','/zhh1/zhanghh');
vertex2.property('age','18');
vertex3=graph.addVertex(label,'zhh1');
vertex3.property('zhang','male');
vertex3.property('uri','/zhh1/zhangheng');
```

When the program executes this line:

```
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'zhh1_index').status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
```

the the log prints these information （and about 30s later, an exception like this: the sleep was interrupt）:

> GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='zhh1_index', targetStatus=ENABLED, notConverged={jiyq=INSTALLED, zhang=INSTALLED, uri=INSTALLED, age=INSTALLED}, converged={}, elapsed=PT1M0.096S]

### I was so confused about this!

## It keeps printing a lot for all indexes I have. Am I doing anything wrong? How to avoid such message?

When I execute the following statement separately, the following exception is reported：

> exception：java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
>   mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex('zhh1_index'),SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object

Answer (score 1):

Your index seems to be stuck in the `INSTALLED` state, which may happening due to a few reasons: please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585417/titan-db-ignoring-index/40591478#40591478) and look at my answer-- specifically bullet numbers 2,3, and 5.

Answer (score 0):

When did you `buildMixedIndex()` ?
REINDEX procedure may be required.

Comment: this mixedIndex has bean build before,  when i try to build a new mixedIndex, this problem will show again