# JanusGraph Index steps

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am using janusgraph 0.2 version and i am connecting from java application, I can create an index please can any one check the following:

```
JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
mgmt.makePropertyKey("Name").dataType(String.class).make();
mgmt.commit();
JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey nameProp = mgmt.getPropertyKey("Name")
mgmt.buildIndex("nameIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(nameProp).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "nameIndex").status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
mgmt = graph.openManagement();
JanusGraphIndex index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("nameIndex");
mgmt.updateIndex(index, SchemaAction.REINDEX);
mgmt.commit();
```

console output is:

```
Key Name has status INSTALLED
Some key(s) on index nameIndex do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: Name=INSTALLED
```

This code doesn't create an index from gremlin console when I check that index:

```
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "nameIndex").call()
```

the result is:

```
==>GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='nameIndex', targetStatus=[REGISTERED], notConverged={Name=ENABLED}, converged={}, elapsed=PT1M0.097S]
```

Comment: Your example is confusing. You create a property key `Name`, then later fetch the property key `FamilyName`. You create an index `nameIndex`, but then the output says `byFamilyNameComposite`, and the last result says `byFirstNameComposite `. It would be helpful if you clean up your example with a single property key and a single composite index.

Comment: I fix it. I replace the variable by their value so I didn't notice. hope this will be better. I want know how to get index status and how to go from installed to registered to enabled.

Comment: Refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585417/titan-db-ignoring-index/40591478#40591478

Comment: See also https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/wiki/Indexing