# Janugraph REINDEX stuck in INSTALLED

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph

I loaded a  graph into Janusgraph from CSV file. Once the data is loaded, I tried to index the graph using `compositeIndex`. Once the index is built the status is stuck in `INSTALLED` status.

```
mgmt=graph.openManagement()
mgmt.getOpenTransactions().size()
==> 0
```

I've all the transactions closed .

```
mgmt.buildIndex("querySpeedUp", Vertex.class).addKey(experimentid).addKey(regionid).addKey(sourcemfield).addKey(zcentroid).addKey(sourcesfield).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'fastTraversal').call()

mgmt.commit()

//opened new connection
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
gremlin> propkey = mgmt.getPropertyKey('experimentid')
==>experimentid
gremlin>  byName.getIndexStatus(propkey);
==>INSTALLED
gremlin> mgmt.updateIndex(byName, SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get()
==>null
gremlin> byName.getIndexStatus(propkey);
==>INSTALLED
gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@5f025000
gremlin> byName.getIndexStatus(propkey);
==>INSTALLED
gremlin> mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'querySpeedUp').call()
==>GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='querySpeedUp', targetStatus=[REGISTERED], notConverged={sourcemfield=INSTALLED, sourcesfield=INSTALLED, regionid=INSTALLED, zcentroid=INSTALLED, experimentid=INSTALLED}, converged={}, elapsed=PT1M0.099S]
```

I've checked various sources [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/janusgraph-users/hcctNlwPatI) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/janusgraph-users/GfYM538KsTo) but didn't help

Comment: Did you see this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40585417/6753576)? This is probably the biggest problem users have right now with JanusGraph, see also these [two](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/460) [issues](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/461).
The short version is that JanusGraph needs to reindex all data already present in the graph.

In general, I would recommend that you try to always create the schema first, including all indices, and then insert the data with this schema.

Comment: @FlorianHockmann I did see the other SO question. It didn't help, I checked the github issue, it again points to the above mentioned SO post

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for others who get stuck with this, I found I had to call `graph.tx().commit()` after the `mgmt.commit()` and it fixed it for me.